# Query View to show current week days

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to show the current weekdays of the week I am in when I run my query but I am getting an error message. I had seen a post on here that I had copied the code  and it worked but somehow my query got changed and is now not working. Here is the code I copied and when it ran it showed a list of the current dates of this week.

```
WITH DAYSOFTHEWEEK
AS
(
    SELECT 0 AS DAY

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DAY + 1 AS Expr1
    FROM dbo.DaysoftheWeek AS DAYSOFTHEWEEK_2
    WHERE (DAY < 4)
)
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, DAY, DATEADD(DAY, 2 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())), CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))) AS DAY_OF_THE_WEEK
FROM DAYSOFTHEWEEK AS DAYSOFTHEWEEK_1
GROUP BY DAY
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Just remove "dbo.". DaysoftheWeek is a CTE (Common Table Expression) and doesn't need the schema prefix, since is not an object in the database.

Comment: Invalid column name 'DAY'

Comment: Pepelui360- that worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `dbo` from the `WITH` Clause.

Try This

```
WITH DAYSOFTHEWEEK
AS
(
    SELECT 0 AS DAY

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DAY + 1 AS Expr1
    FROM DaysoftheWeek AS DAYSOFTHEWEEK_2
    WHERE (DAY < 4)
)
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, DAY, DATEADD(DAY, 2 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())), CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))) AS DAY_OF_THE_WEEK
FROM DAYSOFTHEWEEK AS DAYSOFTHEWEEK_1
GROUP BY DAY
```